# Как получить второй, третий и т.д. определенный символ?

Tags: java, android

Знаю звучит не особо понятно, поэтому я здесь.

В общем допустим у нас есть текст:

```java
String str = "Just an example text";
```

Тут есть 3 символа "е". Как получить его положение нумерации?
Я использовал indexOf, но получается либо первое, либо последнее(lastIndexOf), а именно определенное не знаю как.

=)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3976656

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вторым аргуметом в метод [`indexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-int-int-) вы можете передать индекс `fromIndex`, начиная с которого нужно выполнить поиск символа.

Поэтому вашу задачу можно решить, последовательно вызвав `indexOf` три раза:

```java
str.indexOf('e', str.indexOf('e', str.indexOf('e') + 1) + 1)
```

То же самое можно сделать в цикле, сделаем такой метод:

```java
public static int indexOf(String s, char c, int n) {
    int fromIndex = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        fromIndex = s.indexOf(c, fromIndex + 1);
    }
    return fromIndex;
}
```

Использование:

```java
indexOf(str, 'e', 3)
```

Результат:

```
17
```

Comment: Спасибо вам! Помогли =)